# 404 on .cshtml files (IIS 6.0)

Tags: iis, iis-6, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET WebPages (Not MVC) site up and running with IIS 6, but I can't get it to serve .cshtml pages - It just spits back a 404 error every time.  I've confirmed that it can serve plain .html pages with no problem.  So far, I've done the following:

- Install ASP.NET 4.0 (aspnet_regiis -i)
- Configure site to use ASP.NET 4.0 (aspnet_regiis -s ...)
- Allow ASP.NET v4.0 Web Service Extension
- Map aspnet_isapi.dll as handler for .cshtml files in Application Configuration
- Ensure only ASP.NET 4.0 applications are in the app pool
- Add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to web.config
- Ensure that necessary .dll's are in the site's bin folder

I have a working site on the same framework that I set up a while back (And failed to document my process, lesson learned), so I tried exporting that site's config, creating a new site from file, and pointing it at the proper directory for the new site, but I'm still getting a 404.

Anyone have a clue as to what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the application to the server as a virtual directory or an application? If you add as a virtual directory than the server won't execute and will instead just serve it as files.

Comment: It's a virtual directory, but so is the sister site, and that's not having any issue with dynamic content.

Comment: Try recreating as an application. I ran into a similar problem a few weeks ago and recreating as an application fixed it for me.

Comment: While I wait for our hosting company to set up headers for your suggestion, does it make any difference if I tell you that .aspx files serve fine out of the virtual directory?  If it wasn't serving dynamic content, that would fail too, wouldn't it?